Find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x} \cdot\int_0^{2022x}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|} \, \mathrm dt$
How to find the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x} \cdot\int_0^{2022x}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|} \, \mathrm dt \quad ?$$
I had an idea that $\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}$ changes from $0$ to $1$, then $t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}$ equals either $0$ or $t$. Therefore we get $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2022^2x}{2}.$$
This limit can be calculated, but I'm not entirely sure that this is the right way. If we consider the function $t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}$, it is equal to $0$ at $t=0$ and t=$\frac{2}{\pi+2n\pi}$ for $n$ integer values. Then, the integral can be expanded into a sum of integrals
$$\int_0^{2022x}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}\mathrm dt=\int_\tfrac{2}{\pi}^{2022x}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}\mathrm dt + \int\limits_\tfrac{2}{3\pi}^{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}\mathrm dt + \int\limits_\tfrac{2}{5\pi}^{\tfrac{2}{3\pi}}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}\mathrm dt + \ldots + \int\limits_\tfrac{2}{\pi+2n\pi}^{\tfrac{2}{\pi+2(n-1)\pi}}t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}\mathrm dt$$
but in this case, then I don't know how to find the integral $ \int{t\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right|}}\mathrm dt$.
Please help me solve this problem.

$\frac 1 x \int_0^{ax} f(t)dt \to af(0)$ as $x \to 0+$. No need to evaluate the integral. In this case the limit is $0$.

After dividing by $2022$ and letting $g(t)=t \sqrt{|\cos 1/t|} $, the expression changes to $2022 \times \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2022x}\int_0^{2022x} g(t)dt$. $\lim_{t \to 0^+} g(t) = 0$ by the squeeze theorem. Now, let $u=2022x$ in the previous limit and the problem is equivalent to  this post.
